# How to efficiently use android-architecture-components?

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-architecture-components

Recently, I learned about using android architecture components. And I have a question about `ViewModel`:

According to the architecture design guideline, we can understand that data is the core of the entire application. ViewModel is used to manager data, and the repository is used to fetching data from network or database.

If you have a UI that handles user interaction logic only, But it's almost impossible to get data from a network or a database, So the interactive logic code should be in `ViewModel` or `Activity`/`Fragment`.

In another interface, there is both logical interaction and data acquisition, should I put the interactive logic code into ViewModel or activity/fragment?

Comment: `In another interface, there is both logical interaction and data acquisition` Can you elaborate that part?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are referring to the popular `MVP` pattern in Android.
In the past it was common to see huge `Activity` class that handles all the logic that belongs to that `Activity`.

If you are indeed referring to `MVP`, then you might like the idea of taking methods that can be separated from the `activity` to perform the logic in what is called `presenter`, and leave the `activity` to worry about rendering. If you want to take that even further, you can also create a class that behaves like a network/database `interactor` and only use it to fetch data, called from and only from the `presenter`.

Model is just POJO.

it goes like this:

- activity --> tells the presenter, `hey, a button was pressed, what
  should I do?`
- presenter --> responds by saying, `activity, render that error
  dialog`

You don't have to use libraries to accomplish this, but you will find it to be more effective if combined with `dependency injection` libraries like the popular framework Dagger.

Comment: I think the OP is referring to MVVM pattern.

Comment: I used to use the MVP,  I am familiar with this pattern. I just want to know where to handle the logic interaction when using the android architecture components.